# how to get complete startup time on solaris

Tags: solaris, uptime

I'm struggling to find a command or even a way to find the complete startup time on my `Solaris`(sun4u sparc SUNW,Netra-T12) box

## Solaris

`who -b` gives me `Jun 22 11:09` but no year

same with `last reboot | head -n 1`

However in my `Linux`(GNU/Linux x86_64) boxes i'm able to get the full startup time

## Linux

`who -b` gives me `2014-08-23 11:09`

Any help?

**EDIT**

output of  `apptrace uptime 2>&1`

```
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:int atexit(int (*)() = 0xff3c59ec)
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:atexit()
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:int atexit(int (*)() = 0x10ae8)
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:atexit()
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * setlocale(int = 0x6, const char * = 0x10af8 "")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:setlocale() = 0xfefdb25e
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * textdomain(const char * = 0x10afc "SUNW_OST_OSCMD")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:textdomain() = 0x22b58
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:sysinfo(0x202, 0xffbff97f, 0x1) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:void * malloc(size_t = 0x73)
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:malloc() = 0x23158
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:sysinfo(0x202, 0x23158, 0x73) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:const char * getexecname(void)
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:getexecname() = 0xffbfffc5
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:strlen(0xffbfffc5, 0x23158, 0x10800) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:void * malloc(size_t = 0x82)
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:malloc() = 0x231d8
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcpy(0x231d8, 0xffbfffc5, 0xffbfffd4) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strrchr(const char * = 0x231d8 "/usr/bin/uptime", int = 0x2f)
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strrchr() = 0x231e0
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:strlen(0x231d8, 0x2f, 0x231eb) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strtok(char * = 0x23158 "sparcv9+vis2 sparcv9+vis sparcv9 sparcv8plus+vis2 sparcv8plus+vis sparcv8plus sparcv8 sparcv8-fsmuld sparcv7 sparc", const char * = 0x10b60 " ")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strtok() = 0x23158
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcpy(0x231e1, 0x23158, 0x231e1) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strcat(char * = 0x231e1 "sparcv9+vis2", const char * = 0x10b64 "/")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcat() = 0x231e1
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strcat(char * = 0x231e1 "sparcv9+vis2/", const char * = 0xffbfffce "uptime")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcat() = 0x231e1
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:access(0x231d8, 0x1, 0x231f1) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strtok(char * = 0x0 <NULL>, const char * = 0x10b84 " ")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strtok() = 0x23165
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcpy(0x231e1, 0x23165, 0x231f1) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strcat(char * = 0x231e1 "sparcv9+vis", const char * = 0x10b64 "/")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcat() = 0x231e1
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strcat(char * = 0x231e1 "sparcv9+vis/", const char * = 0xffbfffce "uptime")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcat() = 0x231e1
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:access(0x231d8, 0x1, 0x231f0) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strtok(char * = 0x0 <NULL>, const char * = 0x10b84 " ")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strtok() = 0x23171
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcpy(0x231e1, 0x23171, 0x231f0) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strcat(char * = 0x231e1 "sparcv9", const char * = 0x10b64 "/")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcat() = 0x231e1
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:char * strcat(char * = 0x231e1 "sparcv9/", const char * = 0xffbfffce "uptime")
<- uptime   -> libc.so.1:strcat() = 0x231e1
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:access(0x231d8, 0x1, 0x231ec) ** NR
-> uptime   -> libc.so.1:execve(0x231d8, 0xffbff9e4, 0xffbff9ec) ** NR
ld.so.1: uptime: warning: /usr/lib/abi/sparcv9/apptrace.so.1: open failed: illegal insecure pathname
ld.so.1: uptime: warning: /usr/lib/abi/sparcv9/apptrace.so.1: audit initialization failure: disabled
  3:26pm  up 270 day(s), 13:42,  2 users,  load average: 2.08, 2.07, 2.07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hackish way to get the boot time on Solaris 10 under `ksh` or `bash`:

```
perl -le "print scalar localtime hex(\"$(apptrace -v getutxent uptime 2>&1 | nawk '
/ut_type:/ {if($3=="0x2"){boot=1}}
boot == 1 && $0 ~ ".*tv_sec:.*" {sub("0x","",$3);print $3;exit}')\")"
```

Note that you need to be root to run it on Solaris 10 but not on Solaris 11.

---

**Edit:
Here is a much simpler way that doesn't requires root privileges:**

```
perl -le "print scalar localtime $(kstat -pn system_misc -s boot_time|cut -f 2)"
```

Comment: getting `bash: 1900 +  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")`

Comment: What precise Solaris release are you using?

Comment: And is `apptrace` installed?

Comment: `SunOS  5.10 Generic_141444-09 sun4v sparc SUNW,T5240`

Comment: What contains `/etc/release`?

Comment: ` Solaris 10 5/09 s10s_u7wos_08 SPARC Copyright 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.Use is subject to license terms. Assembled 30 March 2009`

Comment: What reports `apptrace uptime 2>&1 | grep "time()"`?

Comment: `apptrace uptime 2>&1 | grep "time()"` gives me nothing and the return code is `1` means grep command is failing to find `time()`

Comment: `apptrace uptime 2>&1 | wc -l`?

Comment: `apptrace uptime 2>&1 | wc -l` gives me `49`....I have even edited the question to have the output of `apptrace uptime 2>&1`

Comment: My bad, there was a couple of issues. Answer updated with a working solution as long as you can run it as root.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot become root on the server...but I ran your command anyway, I did get the year this time but not sure if it's correct...
`Thu Jan  1 09:00:00 1970`

Comment: yeah i wasn't even born then :D Anyways...so you think if i run it as root it'll give me the correct year?